# Why my angular app stuck in loading when I change bootstrap order?

Tags: angular, typescript

I did my first component, and it works fine.
The second component also works fine.
But, when I add both components to app.module.ts bootstrap, depending on the order, it stays loading forever.

**index.html:**

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MyFirstApp</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--app-my1>loading...</app-my1-->
    <app-my2>loading2...</app-my2>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { My1 } from './my1/my1.component';
import { My2 } from './my2/my2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    My1,
    My2
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [My2] // if I use this line, it works
  bootstrap: [My2, My1] // if I use this line, it works
  bootstrap: [My1, My2] // if I use this line, it stays loading forever, why?
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, if I uncomment app-my1 on index.html, it works. But should commenting this line make the app stuck in loading? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by a deleted answer, there's a error in the console, `The selector "app-my1" did not match any elements`. Looks like if it doesn't find the element mentioned on bootstrap, it immediately breaks. My initial thought was it would be ignored and continue.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap should contains only the root component (AppComponent). 
You can add your two new components in the app component as normal tags and it will work fine.

Comment: Why? Depending no the order it works... I would like to really understand.

Comment: When you add a component in your bootstrap array angular will search the component tag in the index.html. When you comment the first component tag it will stuck directly. if you do the inverse it will stuck also i think (comment <app-my2>) ==> bootstrap: [My2, My1] will do the same behavior. Finally your code is wrog you should put the AppComponent in bootstrap array and write your tags in AppComponent not index.html

Answer (score 0):

your components should only show up in the declarations section. no where else.

bootstrap should look like this: `bootstrap: [AppComponent]`

Comment: Why? Depending no the order it works... I would like to really understand.

Comment: you are typing gibberish into your code and then asking why it's not working? bootstrap is supposed to point to your app component, not each individual component.

Comment: My focus is to understand. If someday I get an app stuck in loading, now I know it may be something with the bootstrap. Still, I would like to understand it deeper. Is the bootstrap meant to receive only one item? So why it receives an array? There's something more to be understood here...

Comment: ok maybe someone else can shed some light. my guess is that's just how it's set up to work. it's like asking, "why doesn't my app work when I type `@NgModuleXXX({})` instead of `@NgModule({})`?

Comment: The answer for that would be "it's the annotation name", nothing more to be understood there. Different from my question.